# cursor/keyup not working in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have made following code :

```
(function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#custom_coverage').keyup(function () {
             this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
         });
     });
 }(jQuery));
```

and

```
<input id="custom_coverage" class="restorable" type="text" data-original-value="100" value="100" name="custom_coverage">
```

The script is working fine, but in Chrome you can't move your cursor in the input field with the -> or <- on the keyboard.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing the value the cursor gets moved to the end of the value. If you want to stop that from happening do the update `onChange` or `onBlur` instead :

```
(function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#custom_coverage').change(function () {
             this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
         });
     });
 }(jQuery));
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8EaAu/)